# How to resolve Projection library error. proj error "Permission denied" in MapServer on IIS

Tags: mapserver, windows-7, iis

I'm trying to get MapServer up and running under IIS on my Windows 7 x64 machine.

I've installed the latest 7.0.1 release msi from [GISInternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php)

Added mapserv.exe to the Allowed list in the ISAPI and CGI restrictions

Created a map file, and tested it locally and it generates the expected image

But when I browse to localhost, http://localhost/mapserver/mapserv.exe?map=test.map&mode=map, I get an error ...

```
msProcessProjection(): Projection library error. proj error "Permission denied" for "init=epsg:4326"
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps or not, but out of interest, in your map file do you directly reference the location of the epsg files, like `CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:/somedir/proj/nad/"`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting out the permissions may be a pain, I would try putting the epsg files in a location that you know IIS will read, then reference that location through the map file through a CONFIG statement.

As a get around instead of referencing the epsg look-up file to get the definition of epsg:4326 you can use the definition directly in the map file like:

```
PROJECTION
    # replace 
    # "init=epsg:4326"
    # with:
    "proj=longlat"
    "datum=WGS84"
    "no_defs"
END
```